# Inserting tabbed views for already created activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, tabs

I am new to android and stackoverflow so forgive if it sounds or reads silly. I have a listview of suppose 10 job details. The list consists of only the names of the jobs. When I tap on any name, I want to open two tabbed views. The first tab would contain further details of the job and the second tab would contain a data entry page which will take input from the user for storage. All the job details (names and further details) are parsed from a json string fetched from the web.

Now, I have created the listview and the details page (containing further details of a single job). But I can't implement the tabbed view on the details page, i.e., I can't make a normal activity tabbed. Please help.

Note: The job list page gets all the details too, but in the XML the visibility of all the details except the job name is kept at "gone".

Ijob.java (Job list activity)

```
package com.example.administrator.signin;

import com.example.administrator.signin.R;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

 import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Ijob extends ListActivity {

  private ProgressDialog pDialog;

  // URL to get contacts JSON



    // JSON Node names

private static final String TAG_CON_NO = "CONSUMER_NO";
private static final String TAG_MET_NO = "METER_NO";
private static final String TAG_REC_ON = "RECEIVED_ON";
private static final String TAG_CON_NAME = "CON_NAME";
//private static final String TAG_CON_CAT = "CON_CAT";
private static final String TAG_MET_RAT = "MET_RAT";
private static final String TAG_CON_ADD = "CON_ADD";
//private static final String TAG_CON_ACC_ADD = "CON_ACC_ADD";
private static final String TAG_COM_RSN = "COM_RSN";

private static final String TAG_M_REF = "M_REF";
private static final String TAG_M_DATE = "M_DATE";
//  //private static final String TAG_CON_CAT = " ";
private static final String TAG_PREV_DATA = "PREV_DATA";
private static final String TAG_TELE_NO = "TELE_NO";
private static final String TAG_IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG =     "IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG";
private static final String TAG_LCC_LRO_ROM = "LCC_LRO_ROM";


    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jobList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ijob);

    jobList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String CONSUMER_NO = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CON_NO))
                    .getText().toString();
            String METER_NO = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.MET_NO))
                    .getText().toString();
            String MET_RAT = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.MET_RAT))
                    .getText().toString();
            String REC_ON = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.REC_ON))
                    .getText().toString();
            String CON_NAME = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CON_NAME))
                    .getText().toString();
            String CON_ADD = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.CON_ADD))
                    .getText().toString();
            String COM_RSN = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.COM_RSN))
                .getText().toString();
            String M_REF = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.M_REF))
                    .getText().toString();
            String M_DATE = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.M_DATE))
                    .getText().toString();
            String PREV_DATA = ((TextView)     view.findViewById(R.id.PREV_DATA)).getText().toString();
            String TELE_NO = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.TELE_NO))
                    .getText().toString();
            String IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG = ((TextView)     view.findViewById(R.id.IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG))
                    .getText().toString();
            String LCC_LRO_ROM = ((TextView)     view.findViewById(R.id.LCC_LRO_ROM))
                    .getText().toString();


            // Starting single contact activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleContactActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_CON_NO, CONSUMER_NO);
            in.putExtra(TAG_MET_NO, METER_NO);
            in.putExtra(TAG_MET_RAT, MET_RAT);
            in.putExtra(TAG_REC_ON, REC_ON);
            in.putExtra(TAG_CON_NAME, CON_NAME);
            in.putExtra(TAG_CON_ADD, CON_ADD);
            in.putExtra(TAG_COM_RSN, COM_RSN);
            in.putExtra(TAG_M_REF, M_REF);
            in.putExtra(TAG_M_DATE, M_DATE);
            in.putExtra(TAG_PREV_DATA, PREV_DATA);
            in.putExtra(TAG_TELE_NO, TELE_NO);
            in.putExtra(TAG_IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG, IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG);
            in.putExtra(TAG_LCC_LRO_ROM, LCC_LRO_ROM);


            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Ijob.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String aid = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        String url = "http://00.00.00.00/fetch_emp_1.jsp?ecd=" + aid;
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
//                  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONArray jobs = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                // Getting JSON Array node
//                  jobs = jsonObj.getJSONArray("");

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jobs.getJSONObject(i);

                    String CON_NO = c.getString(TAG_CON_NO);//  +" - "+c.getString(TAG_CON_CAT);
                    String MET_NO = c.getString(TAG_MET_NO);
                    String MET_RAT = c.getString(TAG_MET_RAT);
                    String REC_ON = c.getString(TAG_REC_ON);
                    String CON_NAME = (i + 1) + " . " + c.getString(TAG_CON_NAME);
                    String CON_ADD = c.getString(TAG_CON_ADD); //+" "+c.getString(TAG_CON_ACC_ADD);
                    String COM_RSN = c.getString(TAG_COM_RSN);
                    String M_REF = c.getString(TAG_M_REF);
                    String M_DATE = c.getString(TAG_M_DATE);
                    String PREV_DATA = c.getString(TAG_PREV_DATA);
                    String TELE_NO = c.getString(TAG_TELE_NO);
                    String IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG = c.getString(TAG_IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG);
                    String LCC_LRO_ROM = c.getString(TAG_LCC_LRO_ROM);

                    // tmp hashmap for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_CON_NO, CON_NO);
                    contact.put(TAG_MET_NO, MET_NO);
                    contact.put(TAG_MET_RAT, MET_RAT);
                    contact.put(TAG_REC_ON, REC_ON);
                    contact.put(TAG_CON_NAME, CON_NAME);
                    contact.put(TAG_CON_ADD, CON_ADD);
                    contact.put(TAG_COM_RSN, COM_RSN);

                    contact.put(TAG_M_REF, M_REF);
                    contact.put(TAG_M_DATE, M_DATE);
                    contact.put(TAG_PREV_DATA, PREV_DATA);
                    contact.put(TAG_TELE_NO, TELE_NO);
                    contact.put(TAG_IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG, IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG);
                    contact.put(TAG_LCC_LRO_ROM, LCC_LRO_ROM);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    jobList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                Ijob.this, jobList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{TAG_CON_NO, TAG_MET_NO, TAG_MET_RAT,
                TAG_REC_ON, TAG_CON_NAME, TAG_CON_ADD, TAG_COM_RSN, TAG_M_REF, TAG_M_DATE, TAG_PREV_DATA, TAG_TELE_NO, TAG_IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG, TAG_LCC_LRO_ROM}, new int[]{R.id.CON_NO,
                R.id.MET_NO, R.id.MET_RAT, R.id.REC_ON, R.id.CON_NAME, R.id.CON_ADD, R.id.COM_RSN, R.id.M_REF, R.id.M_DATE, R.id.PREV_DATA, R.id.TELE_NO, R.id.IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG, R.id.LCC_LRO_ROM});

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}



}
```

And the single job details page is like this:

```
package com.example.administrator.signin;

 import android.app.ActionBar;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.TextView;






 public class SingleContactActivity  extends Activity {


// JSON node keys
private static final String TAG_CON_NO = "CONSUMER_NO";
private static final String TAG_MET_NO = "METER_NO";
private static final String TAG_REC_ON = "RECEIVED_ON";
private static final String TAG_CON_NAME = "CON_NAME";
private static final String TAG_CON_ADD = "CON_ADD";
private static final String TAG_COM_RSN = "COM_RSN";
private static final String TAG_MET_RAT = "MET_RAT";

private static final String TAG_M_REF = "M_REF";
private static final String TAG_M_DATE = "M_DATE";
//private static final String TAG_CON_CAT = " ";


private static final String TAG_PREV_DATA = "PREV_DATA";
private static final String TAG_TELE_NO = "TELE_NO";
private static final String TAG_IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG = "IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG";
private static final String TAG_LCC_LRO_ROM = "LCC_LRO_ROM";






@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_contact);


    // getting intent data
    Intent in = getIntent();

    // Get JSON values from previous intent
    String CON_NO = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CON_NO);
    String MET_NO = in.getStringExtra(TAG_MET_NO);
    String REC_ON = in.getStringExtra(TAG_REC_ON);
    String CON_NAME = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CON_NAME);
    String CON_ADD = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CON_ADD);
    String COM_RSN = in.getStringExtra(TAG_COM_RSN);


    String MET_RAT = in.getStringExtra(TAG_MET_RAT);
    //String CON_CAT = in.getStringExtra(TAG_CON_CAT);

    String MET_REF = in.getStringExtra(TAG_M_REF);
    String M_DATE = in.getStringExtra(TAG_M_DATE);
    String PREV_DATA = in.getStringExtra(TAG_PREV_DATA);
    String IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG = in.getStringExtra(TAG_IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG);
    String LCC_LRO_ROM = in.getStringExtra(TAG_LCC_LRO_ROM);

    String TELE_NO = in.getStringExtra(TAG_TELE_NO);


    //PARSING THE STRING ===================


    String delims = "[;]";

    String[] CON_NAME_tokens = CON_NAME.split(" . ");


    String[] PREV_DATA_tokens = PREV_DATA.split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_1_final = PREV_DATA_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_2_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[1].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_2_final = MM_YY_2_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_3_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[2].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_3_final = MM_YY_3_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_4_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[3].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_4_final = MM_YY_4_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_5_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[4].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_5_final = MM_YY_5_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_6_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[5].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_6_final = MM_YY_6_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_7_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[6].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_7_final = MM_YY_7_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_8_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[7].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_8_final = MM_YY_8_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_9_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[8].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_9_final = MM_YY_9_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_10_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[9].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_10_final = MM_YY_10_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_11_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[10].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_11_final = MM_YY_11_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_12_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[11].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_12_final = MM_YY_12_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_13_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[12].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_13_final = MM_YY_13_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_14_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[13].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_14_final = MM_YY_14_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_15_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[14].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_15_final = MM_YY_15_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_16_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[15].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_16_final = MM_YY_16_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_17_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[16].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_17_final = MM_YY_17_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_18_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[17].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_18_final = MM_YY_18_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_19_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[18].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_19_final = MM_YY_18_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_20_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[19].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_20_final = MM_YY_20_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_21_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[20].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_21_final = MM_YY_21_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_22_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[21].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_22_final = MM_YY_22_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_23_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[22].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_23_final = MM_YY_23_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] MM_YY_24_tokens = PREV_DATA_tokens[23].split(delims);
    String[] MM_YY_24_final = MM_YY_24_tokens[0].split(":");


    String[] IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG_tokens =
IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG.split(delims);
    String[] IE_date_final = IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] Present_Rdg_tokens =            IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG_tokens[1].split(delims);
    String[] Present_Rdg_final = Present_Rdg_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] Last_Rdg_tokens = IE_DT_N_PRSNT_PREV_RDG_tokens[2].split(delims);
    String[] Last_Rdg_final = Last_Rdg_tokens[0].split(":");


    String[] LCC_LRO_ROM_tokens = LCC_LRO_ROM.split(delims);
    String[] LCC_Act_final = LCC_LRO_ROM_tokens[0].split(":");

    String[] Last_Read_On_tokens = LCC_LRO_ROM_tokens[1].split(delims);
    String[] Last_Read_On_final = Last_Read_On_tokens[0].split(":");


    String[] R_no_tokens = LCC_LRO_ROM_tokens[2].split(delims);
    String[] R_no_final = R_no_tokens[0].split("\\s");

    String[] O_no_tokens = LCC_LRO_ROM_tokens[3].split(delims);
    String[] O_no_final = R_no_tokens[0].split("\\s");

    String[] M_no_tokens = LCC_LRO_ROM_tokens[4].split(delims);
    String[] M_no_final = R_no_tokens[0].split("\\s");


    //END OF PARSING STRINGS==================


    // Displaying all values on the screen
    TextView lblMref = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.m_ref);
    TextView lblMdate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.m_date);
    TextView lblRec_On = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rec_on_label);
    TextView lblCons_No = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.con_no_label);
    TextView lblMet_No = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.met_no_label);
    TextView lblCons_Name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.con_name_label);
    TextView lblCons_Addr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.con_add_label);
    TextView lblComp_Reason = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.com_rsn_label);
    TextView lblMet_Rat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.met_rat_label);
    TextView lblCon_Cat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.con_cat_label);
    TextView lblTele_No = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tele_no_label);

    TextView lblIE_Date_final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.IE_label);
    TextView lblPresent_Rdng_final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.present_reading_label);
    TextView lblLast_Rdng_final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prev_reading_label);

    TextView lblLCC_Act_final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lcc_action_label);
    TextView lblLast_read_On_final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_read_label);
    TextView lblR_no_final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.R_no_label);
    TextView lblO_no_final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.O_no_label);
    TextView lblM_no_final = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.M_no_label);


    TextView lblMMYY_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_1);
    TextView lblMMYY_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_2);
    TextView lblMMYY_3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_3);
    TextView lblMMYY_4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_4);
    TextView lblMMYY_5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_5);
    TextView lblMMYY_6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_6);
    TextView lblMMYY_7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_7);
    TextView lblMMYY_8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_8);
    TextView lblMMYY_9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_9);
    TextView lblMMYY_10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_10);
    TextView lblMMYY_11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_11);
    TextView lblMMYY_12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_12);
    TextView lblMMYY_13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_13);
    TextView lblMMYY_14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_14);
    TextView lblMMYY_15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_15);
    TextView lblMMYY_16 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_16);
    TextView lblMMYY_17 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_17);
    TextView lblMMYY_18 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_18);
    TextView lblMMYY_19 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_19);
    TextView lblMMYY_20 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_20);
    TextView lblMMYY_21 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_21);
    TextView lblMMYY_22 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_22);
    TextView lblMMYY_23 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_23);
    TextView lblMMYY_24 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_24);

    TextView lblCont_1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_1_content);
    TextView lblCont_2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_2_content);
    TextView lblCont_3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_3_content);
    TextView lblCont_4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_4_content);
    TextView lblCont_5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_5_content);
    TextView lblCont_6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_6_content);
    TextView lblCont_7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_7_content);
    TextView lblCont_8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_8_content);
    TextView lblCont_9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_9_content);
    TextView lblCont_10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_10_content);
    TextView lblCont_11 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_11_content);
    TextView lblCont_12 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_12_content);
    TextView lblCont_13 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_13_content);
    TextView lblCont_14 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_14_content);
    TextView lblCont_15 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_15_content);
    TextView lblCont_16 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_16_content);
    TextView lblCont_17 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_17_content);
    TextView lblCont_18 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_18_content);
    TextView lblCont_19 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_19_content);
    TextView lblCont_20 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_20_content);
    TextView lblCont_21 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_21_content);
    TextView lblCont_22 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_22_content);
    TextView lblCont_23 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_23_content);
    TextView lblCont_24 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mm_yy_24_content);


    lblMref.setText(MET_REF);
    lblMdate.setText(M_DATE);
    lblRec_On.setText(REC_ON);
    lblCons_No.setText(CON_NO);
    lblMet_No.setText(MET_NO);
    lblCons_Name.setText(CON_NAME_tokens[1]);
    lblCons_Addr.setText(CON_ADD);
    lblComp_Reason.setText(COM_RSN);
    lblMet_Rat.setText(MET_RAT);
    // lblCon_Cat.setText(CON_CAT);

    lblIE_Date_final.setText(IE_date_final[1]);
    lblPresent_Rdng_final.setText(Present_Rdg_final[1]);
    lblLast_Rdng_final.setText(Last_Rdg_final[1]);

    lblLCC_Act_final.setText(LCC_Act_final[1]);
    lblLast_read_On_final.setText(Last_Read_On_final[1]);
    lblR_no_final.setText(R_no_final[2]);
    lblO_no_final.setText(O_no_final[2]);
    lblM_no_final.setText(M_no_final[2]);

    lblTele_No.setText(TELE_NO);


    lblMMYY_1.setText(MM_YY_1_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_2.setText(MM_YY_2_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_3.setText(MM_YY_3_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_4.setText(MM_YY_4_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_5.setText(MM_YY_5_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_6.setText(MM_YY_6_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_7.setText(MM_YY_7_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_8.setText(MM_YY_8_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_9.setText(MM_YY_9_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_10.setText(MM_YY_10_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_11.setText(MM_YY_11_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_12.setText(MM_YY_12_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_13.setText(MM_YY_13_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_14.setText(MM_YY_14_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_15.setText(MM_YY_15_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_16.setText(MM_YY_16_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_17.setText(MM_YY_17_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_18.setText(MM_YY_18_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_19.setText(MM_YY_19_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_20.setText(MM_YY_20_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_21.setText(MM_YY_21_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_22.setText(MM_YY_22_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_23.setText(MM_YY_23_final[0]);
    lblMMYY_24.setText(MM_YY_24_final[0]);


    lblCont_1.setText(MM_YY_1_final[1]);
    lblCont_2.setText(MM_YY_2_final[1]);
    lblCont_3.setText(MM_YY_3_final[1]);
    lblCont_4.setText(MM_YY_4_final[1]);
    lblCont_5.setText(MM_YY_5_final[1]);
    lblCont_6.setText(MM_YY_6_final[1]);
    lblCont_7.setText(MM_YY_7_final[1]);
    lblCont_8.setText(MM_YY_8_final[1]);
    lblCont_9.setText(MM_YY_9_final[1]);
    lblCont_10.setText(MM_YY_10_final[1]);
    lblCont_11.setText(MM_YY_11_final[1]);
    lblCont_12.setText(MM_YY_12_final[1]);
    lblCont_13.setText(MM_YY_13_final[1]);
    lblCont_14.setText(MM_YY_14_final[1]);
    lblCont_15.setText(MM_YY_15_final[1]);
    lblCont_16.setText(MM_YY_16_final[1]);
    lblCont_17.setText(MM_YY_17_final[1]);
    lblCont_18.setText(MM_YY_18_final[1]);
    lblCont_19.setText(MM_YY_19_final[1]);
    lblCont_20.setText(MM_YY_20_final[1]);
    lblCont_21.setText(MM_YY_21_final[1]);
    lblCont_22.setText(MM_YY_22_final[1]);
    lblCont_23.setText(MM_YY_23_final[1]);
    lblCont_24.setText(MM_YY_24_final[1]);


}
}
```

Comment: What you want to know is the way to build two tabbed layout? If so,  read this  tutorial https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout

Comment: @nshmura  Actually how to morph the second detailed info page into a tabbed activity. I want to tap on any item on the list page and want two tabs to open. One will contain the details page. Another will be a data entry activity page (code not included here). Hope I'm clear. thank you.

Comment: I recommend you to read above tutorial and make sample application that has two tabbed layout. Then build application for production.